# 2D numpy array- check to see if all adjacent terms are equal

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, transformation, edge-detection

I am starting with a nxm boolean array, that defines regions- true if it is in the region, false if not.  For example:

```
r = np.array([[ 0,  0,  1,  1,  1],
              [ 0,  1,  1,  0,  0],
              [ 0,  1,  1,  1,  0],
              [ 1,  1,  1,  0,  0],
              [ 1,  1,  0,  0,  0]])
```

The line between regions can be defined as an n-1 x m-1 array, which would represent a 'point' in between each set of four values.  If all 4 surrounding values are the same, you are not on the edge between regions.  If any of the 4 values are different, you are.  For r above:

```
l = np.array([[ 1, 1, 1, 1],
              [ 1, 0, 1, 1],
              [ 1, 0, 1, 1],
              [ 0, 1, 1, 0]])
```

Any thoughts on how this can be done efficiently?  I have tried doing a diff in both directions, but this doubles up.  Is there a 2D diff function?  Some other way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do the test for *points* surrounded by `True`,

```
tmp = r[1:] & r[:-1]
l = np.logical_not(tmp[:, 1:] & tmp[:, :-1])
```

Then you can do the test for *points* surrounded by `False` the same way and combine them,

```
r = np.logical_not(r)
tmp = r[1:] & r[:-1]
l &= np.logical_not(tmp[:, 1:] & tmp[:, :-1])

print l.astype(int)
# [[1 1 1 1]
#  [1 0 1 1]
#  [1 0 1 1]
#  [0 1 1 0]]
```

Comment: Ya, I noticed that, I fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: +1 with the fix, and the question would have been better if the example was correct syntax and easier to test.

Comment: Worked great.  Thanks.  Also, fixed the example syntax.  My bad.

Answer (score 2):

An good answer's already selected, but I like solutions that are easy to write and understand so I'll still post this:

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d
kernel = np.array(((1, 1), (1, 1)))

x = convolve2d(r, kernel, mode="valid")   # sum all the neighboring values (and mode handles the boundary issues)
x[x==4] = 0                               # set the elements that sum to 4 to zero (the ones that sum to 0 are already 0)
x[x>0] = 1                                # anything greater than one is set to 1

[[1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 1 1]
 [1 0 1 1]
 [0 1 1 0]]
```

Comment: Yes/+1, I like this b/c it is certainly easier to read. Because I was curious, I ran some speed tests. My solution is 30% faster on the example array, and *much* faster as the arrays become larger. ;)

Comment: @farenorth: for sure, probably due to all the multiplications.