# Extract the indices of whites surrounded by blacks

Tags: numpy, vector, scipy, scikit-learn, scikit-image

```
import numpy as numpy

data = np.array([[0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [0,*1*, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [1, 0 , 0 , 0 ,*1*, 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [1, 0 , 0 , 0 ,*1*,*1*, 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 0 ,*1*,*1*, 0 , 0 , 1],
                 [1, 0 , 0 , 0 ,*1*, 0 , 1 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0]])
```

I want to extract the indices of the white (ones) patches if the patch is surrounded by blacks (zeros)in all four neighboring pixels.
The expected positions are indicated by italicks.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [2D numpy array- check to see if all adjacent terms are equal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26662055/2d-numpy-array-check-to-see-if-all-adjacent-terms-are-equal)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You've marked points (`*1*`) that have a `1` next to them. Rather than finding *points* surrounded by 0 on all four sides, it looks like you are trying to find contiguous *patches* that don't intersect the edge of the domain.

Comment: @farenorth yes you are right, I'm trying to find contiguous patches that don't intersect the edge of the domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, label all connected objects in the image (the default structuring element considers neighbors in the north-south-east-west directions).  Then, remove any objects touching the border.  The background is labeled as 0, the rest are objects completely surrounded by it.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np

from scipy.ndimage import label
from skimage.segmentation import clear_border

data = np.array([[0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [1, 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [1, 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1],
                 [1, 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0]])

objects, count = label(data)
objects_inside = clear_border(objects)

print((objects_inside != 0).astype(int))
```

Result:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```